# How can I get the default ControlTemplate of DataGridTextColumn?

Tags: wpf

I wanna custom the ControlTemplate of DataGridTextColumn.
I always get the default ControlTemplate via this:
1. Right-click the control.
2. Edit Template.
3. Edit a copy.

Just as the image shows below:
[image]

However, I can see the DataGridTextColumn in the designer so that I can't right click it.

So how can I get the default ControlTemplate of it? Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There are various templates like header and cell used to build out a column that you could alter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/datagrid-styles-and-templates

Comment: @Andy  I want to rewrite it like the excel sheet which can resize width&height any time you want.

Comment: The user can drag row header and column header dividers to resize, straight out the box.

Comment: The datagrid has properties you can set for gridline colour HorizontalGridLinesBrush ="Gray VerticalGridLinesBrush="Gray"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DataGridTextColumn` is not a `Control` and has no `ControlTemplate`.

It generates a `TextBlock` in its `GenerateElement` method and a `TextBox` in its `GenerateEditingElement` method. You'll find the source code [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/DataGridTextColumn.cs,16b7863c7c126e07).

Comment: I hate the border color of this things so I want to rewrite its controltemplate yet.

Comment: As mentioned, there is no template for the column. You may want to define your own custom `DataGridCell` template.

Comment: Let me try. Thank you.

Comment: One can set `Template` in `DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle` to `ControlTemplate`. This works however this controltemplate does not come into edit mode.